# Angular 8 wait for http results in if statement

Tags: angular

I have a component with one method that makes multiple http GET requests. If the first request returns nothing, I perform the next and then the next until one of them returns results.

My problem is that before the first request finishes, the next begins whereas I want it to perform each request one by one.

example of my component code:

```js
input1: Object;
input2: Object;
httpResults: Object;

MainMethod() {
    this.firstGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
    // wait
    if(this.httpResults == []) {
      this.secondGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
      // wait
    }
    else if(this.httpResults == []) {
     this.thirdGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
     // wait
    }
    // -- more requests following the same pattern --
    else {
      return;
    }
}

firstGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.firstGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    this.httpResults = data;
    });
  }
secondGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.secondGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    this.httpResults = data;
        });
      }
thirdGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.thirdGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    this.httpResults = data;
        });
  }
```

All the http requests are small and quick so the waiting time is not a problem. How could I implement my code so that I can wait for each individual request to complete and check whether or not it has returned something?

Comment: requests are async, so you have to go for nested promises or observables

Comment: Why don't you try using promises. You can call the next request in the catch block of first one.

Comment: This is [covered](https://angular.io/guide/observables) [by](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) [the](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Try **forkJoin** observable method. This will group the requests and then wait for them all to return, then you could do something based on that outcome. This will give you an idea - (https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61). Certainly you need to leverage the Rxjs library for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion It's better to use `Promise` to do that.

First of all, modify your service like the following :
Use `Promise` instead of `Observable`

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

   firstGetData(input,input):Promise<any>{
     return this.http.(...).toPromise();
   }

   secondGetData(input,input):Promise<any>{
     return this.http.(...).toPromise();
   }

   thirdGetData(input,input):Promise<any>{
     return this.http.(...).toPromise();
   }
}
```

Then in your component:

```
MainMethod() {

 this.httpService.firstGetData(this.input1.value, this.input2.value)
     .then(data =>{
          this.httpResults = data;
          if(!(this.httpResults == [])){
             throw 'stop-operation'; // stop , because we have data;
          }
          // continue , because we do not have any data in httpResult 
      })
      .then(response=>{
         return this.httpService.secondGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
      })
      .then(data=>{
          this.httpResults = data;
          if(!(this.httpResults == [])){
             throw 'stop-operation'; // stop , because we have data;
          }
          // continue , because we do not have any data in httpResult
      })
      .then(response=>{
         return this.httpService.thirdGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
      })
      .then(data=>{
          this.httpResults = data;
          if(!(this.httpResults == [])){
             throw 'stop-operation'; // stop , because we have data;
          }
          // continue , because we do not have any data in httpResult
      })
      .catch(error=>{
           if(error!=='stop-operation'){
               // this error happend in http request;
           }
       });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this you need to call in complete section.

```
 firstGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
      this.httpService.firstGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
        this.httpResults = data;
        }, err =>{
        }, ()=>{ // When First Request Complete Call Second Request.
        this.secondGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
        });
      }


    secondGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
      this.httpService.secondGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
        this.httpResults = data;
            }, err => {
            }, ()=>{ // When First Request Complete call third request
           this.thirdGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
          });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the next method when handling the current one. You'll get something like this:

```
input1: Object;
input2: Object;
httpResults: Object;

MainMethod() {
    this.firstGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
}

firstGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.firstGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    if(this.httpResults == []) {
      this.secondGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
    } else {
      this.httpResults = data;  
    }
    });
  }
secondGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.secondGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    if(this.httpResults == []) {
      this.thirdGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value);
    } else {
      this.httpResults = data;  
    }
        });
      }
thirdGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
  this.httpService.thirdGetData(input1, input2).subscribe(data =>{
    this.httpResults = data;
        });
  }
```

Since I am not very familiar with threads in Angular, I'm not sure if `httpResults` will be assigned to the resultset of the `GET` request once the if-statement is being executed. If not, you will have to wait for the request thread to finish executing, f.e. with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `concat` (chain requests), `filter` (filter out empty responses), and `take` (the first non-empty result will do) should do what you want:

```
// alter second and thirdGetHttp the same way
firstGetHttp(input1: Object, input2: Object) {     
    return this.httpService.firstGetData(input1, input2)
}

mainMethod() {
    concat(
        this.firstGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value),
        this.secondGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value),
        this.thirdGetHttp(this.input1.value, this.input2.value),
    ).pipe(
        filter(response => response && response.length),
        take(1),
    ).subscribe(data => this.httpResults = data);
```

(And by the way, `this.httpResults == []` is not how you test for an empty array. It'll always evaluate to *false*. Even `[] == []` evaluates to *false*).